# How can I use cloudinary gallery widget with local resources?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I dont want to use cloudinary cloud images. I need to use local
>   resources. Any one have a idea for this?

```
<script src="https://product-gallery.cloudinary.com/all.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>  

<div id="my-gallery" style="max-width:80%;margin:auto">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
const myGallery= cloudinary.galleryWidget({
  container: "#my-gallery",
  cloudName: "demo",
  mediaAssets: [
    {tag: "electric_car_product_gallery_demo"}, // by default mediaType: "image"
    {tag: "electric_car_product_gallery_demo", mediaType: "video"}, 
    {tag: "electric_car_360_product_gallery_demo", mediaType: "spin"}
  ]
});

myGallery.render();
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone is here? :)